# what makes commands not to be recognized by visual studio code terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, command, failed-installation, yarn-v2

where i try running the command yarn create next-app in visual studio code

'C:\Users\username' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Command failed.

what could be causing this error

I was expecting yarn to install successfully and proceed with other areas

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have yarn yet on your computer, you can check this with `yarn --version`. You can install yarn [here](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#windows-stable).